# Does fluentmigrator work with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, fluent-migrator

Does the current iteration of fluentmigrator work with SQL Server 2012? Its not listed under the supported databases.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official support for Sql Server 2012 yet. But it should work if you specify SqlServer2008 as the database type. The differences between Sql Server 2005, 2008 and 2012 are not so significant when using FluentMigrator (Sql Server 2000 is a different story). Some features like the new [sequence object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) have no support so in the meantime will have to be run using Execute.Sql.

UPDATE: I tested FluentMigrator against Sql Server 2012 Express with database type specified as SqlServer2008 and it worked fine.

UPDATE: FluentMigrator now officially supports Sql Server 2012 and Sequences.